# Will the Anatomical Differences in These Humanoids Affect Baby Development?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans

Okay, here are two hypothetical species of the genus *Homo*.  One averages 67 to 84 inches (170-213 cm) in height and 99 to 110 pounds (45-50 kg) in weight and gives birth to twins.  The other averages 43 to 48 inches (110-122 cm) in height and 168 to 200 pounds (76-90 kg) in weight and usually gives birth to just one child.  I have a few more differences in mind, but size in relation to gestation is the focus of this question.  Whereas we humans carry our young in a 280-day gestation, **would the listed differences give these fictional human species different gestation periods, therefore differently developed babies?  If yes, then how?**

Comment: Assuming they have humanlike proportions, your Elves will have problems carrying their young for very long. Narrow hips (the height vs mass shows this) will encourage small births. Having Twins amplifies this. I expect shorter gestation, longer infancy for the Elves, and longer gestation with more developed babies for the Dwarves. Not making this an answer, as I have no clue how to Quantize the answer.

Comment: Actually in humans the time between fertilization and normal full-term birth varies between 255 and 285 days or thereabouts, with an average of 268 days; those 280 days (actuall 282) in the question are the average time since the last menstrual period. The tall thin species (which overlaps the normal range of humans) will likely drift towards the lower end of this interval; the short thick species will do whatever it happens it will do, having no constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Human gestation is mostly a timed balancing of two factors: as long as possible to allow brain development, without allowing the head to get so large that childbirth is fatal to the mother. Obviously childbirth in pre-modern was tragically fatal far more often than we are comfortable thinking about, but that extreme danger is paid for in evolutionary terms by the enormous advantage of large brains.

The mother's hip size and the baby's head are the critical things here: a homonid with narrow hips will probably have a shorter gestation as the larger head that comes from longer gestation would be lethal. Does that smaller head correspond to lower intelligence, or a longer childhood, or a very fragile skull in the baby (human baby skulls aren't fused, a further compromise to allow greater brain growth)? Essentially, any development not happening in the womb either has to happen after birth somehow or is skipped over entirely.

The number of children doesn't really matter so long as there are sufficient resources for care when they are born. Height and weight don't really matter either - it's about pelvis and skull.

Comment: A lot of recent work has shown head size does not matter as much as we thought, human gestation most likely ends when the mothers body can't transport caloric needs to the fetus fast enough anymore. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3458333/

Comment: That's an interesting paper but it is only putting out an alternative hyothesis - maybe there is more out there that points to similar arguments. Personally it doesn't feel compelling though. The mother continues to provide all the baby's nutritional needs for up to six months after birth - if the ability to provide nutrition to the baby was the critical factor would we not expect to see the baby eady to ween very shortly after birth?

Comment: In any event, the paper doesn't take issue with the idea that the birth canal is pretty much at the limit of baby size, it only argues that it could get bigger through evolution if, that was important, and that this wouldn't impede walking too much (by comparing with chimps that really aren't that similar in terms of bipedalism). The paper agrees that longer gestation with implied larger heads are not viable for today's humans. So I think my answer here still works: gestation length is limited by pelvis for homonids and calculating change based on height or weight alone doesn't really work.

Comment: the mother is not supplying the baby with all nutrition, the baby gets its own oxygen and gets let nutrients overall. Maternal metabolic output drops after birth and takes several months to match those just before birth. Gestation length is not limited by pelvis, the human pelvis could easily expand, many women have larger pelvic openings, evolutionarily the pelvis expands to match time of birth not the other way around. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3458333/bin/supp_109_38_15212__index.html and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25902498/

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

It's well documented that across species, body mass generally correlates with gestation period, with larger animals having longer pregnancies than smaller ones. We even see this effect *within* species, with a significant (although weak) association between a human mother's height and the length of her pregnancy, with shorter mothers typically having shorter pregnancies than taller ones. I find it unlikely that there would be no difference whatsoever in the pregnancy length of two species that differed in size by 50%.

These are just trends, however. It might be unexpected for the smaller species to have a pregnancy length equal to or greater than that of the larger species, but biology does all sorts of surprising things.